# SwiftyJSON won't parse a JSON string that will later parse with no issue

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub, swifty-json

I have the following PubNub delegate methods that are getting called in the exact order as declared below.

```
public func pubnubClient(client: PubNub!, didSubscribeOnChannels channels: NSArray!) {
    log.info("Subscribed to \(channels.count) channels")
    PubNub.sendMessage("{\"type\": \"CHAT_MSG\",\"msgId\": \"1233123\",\"text\": \"hello\",\"username\": \"attheodo\",\"uuid\": \"user_1\",\"associatedPlaceId\": 2}", toChannel:pubnubChannels[0])
}

public func pubnubClient(client: PubNub!, subscriptionDidFailWithError error: PNError!){
    log.error("Subscribe Error: \(error)")
}

// MARK: Messages
public func pubnubClient(client: PubNub!, willSendMessage message: PNMessage!) {

    let payload = JSON(message.message)
    println(payload)
    println(payload.rawString())
    println(_stdlib_getTypeName(payload))
    println(payload["type"])


}

public func pubnubClient(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessage!) {

    let payload = JSON(message.message)
    println(payload)
    println(payload.rawString())
    println(_stdlib_getTypeName(payload))
    println(payload["type"])

}
```

The problem is SwiftyJSON will not parse properly the string returned by `willSendMessage` but will parse properly the one returned by `didReceiveMessage` although, to my eyes, it appears that they are exactly the same. It kinda drives me crazy.

Please check the respective console output below:

```
// willSendMessage
{"type": "CHAT_MSG","msgId": "1233123","text": "hello","username":     "attheodo","uuid": "user_1","associatedPlaceId": 2}

Optional("{\"type\": \"CHAT_MSG\",\"msgId\": \"1233123\",\"text\":  \"hello\",\"username\": \"attheodo\",\"uuid\": \"user_1\",\"associatedPlaceId\": 2}")

_TtV10SwiftyJSON4JSON

// cannot find payload["type"]
null

// didReceiveMessage
{
  "username" : "attheodo",
  "uuid" : "user_1",
  "msgId" : "1233123",
  "associatedPlaceId" : 2,
  "type" : "CHAT_MSG",
  "text" : "hello"
}

Optional("{\n  \"username\" : \"attheodo\",\n  \"uuid\" : \"user_1\",\n  \"msgId\" : \"1233123\",\n  \"associatedPlaceId\" : 2,\n  \"type\" : \"CHAT_MSG\",\n  \"text\" : \"hello\"\n}")

_TtV10SwiftyJSON4JSON

// payload["type"] is ok
CHAT_MSG
```

What the @#$! is going on here? Please help, this will put me on meds >:|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PubNub Library will automatically encode/decode JSON for you for object types such as Dictionaries.  Try excluding your use of 3rd party JSON libs and use the native Obj-c dictionaries.